# Hiding DIV elements from browsers built-in find function

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok guys, heres the deal. I have two div's in my page for the purpose of a scrollable table.
That all works fine(I'd post the code but the page is WAY to complicated with all the DB data we bring in. And I don't wanna breach any privacy rules here at my company.) Anyway. I have the two div's containing exactly the same data and I have z-index'd the scrollable div on top of the other one. The hidden div only exists to show the table header. I have to write out the data in both div's so the table header's cells are the correct width because the width fluxuates. Anyway, now that the explination is over, heres the problem. When using CTRL+F to find items in the table. When it finds a single item, it says it found two because it's finding the value in the div thats hidden. Is there anyway in HTML,CSS,JAVASCRIPT to not include the contents of the hidden div in the find function?

Sorry for such a long explination. This is my first question here, just wanted to be thorough.

Thanks guys for any help you can give.

CODE:This writes out the divs and tables

`response.write "<div id='container'>"
response.write "<TABLE BORDER=1 style='border: solid; ' WIDTH='100%'>"
call writeHeader
call writeData
response.write "</table><div id='divToShow'><TABLE BORDER=1  style='background-color: white;border: solid;' WIDTH='100%'>"
objrst.Close
objRst.Open Sql
call writeData
call writeHeader
response.write "</div></table></div>"`

CSS:

```
<style>
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#divToShow {
    width: calc(100% + 5px);
    height: 650px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 46;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#divToShow {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to show the data, but you do have to show the code that shows the data. complicated or not, its no excuse here.

Comment: Is the DIV actually hidden, or just below the other's z-index?

Comment: I take that the "hidden" table content is not hidden or else the column widths wouldn't adjust to it. Also, most browsers will not find text in display:none elements.

Comment: If you set display:none or visibility:hidden to element you want to hide - there is no way it can be found with ctrl + f

Comment: Attempting to post a little of the code in here. Says its too long. Sorry for my inexperiance with this site.

Comment: Can you not just hide doubled content instead of z-indexing? Leave the table headers displayed, and hide the table data

Comment: If i set visibility to hidden or display to none it hides the table header as well. The header is the whole purpose of the hidden div. i leave the header visible to produce a table with a header that never moves.

Comment: What about hiding just rows with data though? It's hard to say something sensible without seeing the code, but I'm sure there is some more appropriate way of dealing with this issue without duplicating the elements and stacking them up.

Comment: My understanding was that modern data grids maintained and searched data in an array, so what you see is only the printed representation.

Comment: If i hide the data rows it shrinks the header cells to fit the contect of the header cells. But the issue is that the data in the table itself changes ofter so the cells are never the same size. thats why I'm writing the data twice. so the header cells formulate correctly.

Comment: Add headers only, and update the cell-width with JavaScript.

Comment: without writing out the data, how will javascript be able to size the cells correctly?

Comment: Is your scrolling horizontal or vertical? If its all about preserving vertical scrolling, this might be interesting to you: http://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/

Comment: The scrolling is vertical only. If i'm reading this jfiddle correctly, the cell sizes are set and wont resize it the table TD cells content changes.

Comment: It was just first example I reached after googling "tables with fixed headers". There is plethora of those and I'm sure you'll find one which suits you. One more from code pen: http://codepen.io/jgx/pen/wiIGc

Comment: Thanks for researching. I've looked at a ton of the examples out there. the issue is that when the tables td cell size changes, the headers do not.

Comment: I think codepen example does just that. I did some edits with data, and headers too, and it expands horizontally. There is a kind of exhaustive guide to the tables from Chris Coyer here: [link](http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/), which I recommend to go through. maybe you'll find it helpful. I'd personally tried to stick to the css way of tackling issue of fixed header, rather than creating hidden elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, having visibility set to hidden does what you asked for:

```
td {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

This example illustrate it: http://jsfiddle.net/c26pn017/

But as I stated in the comment I'd rather dig to find out how to build the fixed header table instead.

Comment: Thank You. After Digging into it with the visibility option and tweaking this 3500+line program to work with it. I finally got it o work correctly. This did the trick!! Thanks